# C++ arrays [from:to]

Tags: c++, arrays, array-splice

How can i do that in C++?
in python is

```
example = [u'one', u'two', u'three', u'four']
print example[1:3]
```

How can i do that in C++ (i missing this function)
I need rewrite this to C++

```
while i<len(a)-1:
                if (a[i]=='\x00' or a[i]=='\x04') and (eval("0x"+(a[i-1].encode("hex"))) in range(32-(4*eval((a[i].encode("hex")))),128-(12*eval((a[i].encode("hex")))))):
                    st+=a[i-1:i+1]
                    i+=2;continue
                elif st=='':
                    i+=1;continue
                elif len(st)>=4 and (a[i-1:i+1]=='\x00\x00' or a[i-1:i+1]=='\x0a\x00' or a[i-1:i+1]=='\x09\x00' or a[i-1:i+1]=='\x0d\x00'):
                    s.STRINGS.append([st.decode("utf-16le"),0xffffff])
                    s.INDEX.append(iCodeOffset+i-1-len(st))
                    st=''
                    i=i-1;continue
                else:
                    st=''
                    i=i-1;continue
```

I need list of strings from binary files without using string.exe

THX for advance
Benecore

Comment: Since you are addressing the question to C++ community, please explain what the python program does and what have you tried in converting to C++ and difficulties faced.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that returns a new spliced vector given then old one. It does only the most basic splicing (from:to), and only in one direction (not sure if from is greater than to but I believe python reverses the output).

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> splice(const std::vector<T> in, int from, int to)
{
    if (to < from) std::swap(to, from);

    std::vector<T> ret(to - from + 1);

    for (to -= from; to + 1; to--)
    {
        ret[to] = in[from + to];
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no immediate replacement for this in C++, as C++ is not python and has its own idioms that work differently.

To begin with, for strings you can use the specific [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

For more generic containers you should know C++ usually works iterator based when operating on elements of said container. For example suppose you want to compare elements in a vector, you'd do something like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = {1,2,3,4};
    std::vector<int> b = {1,2,10,4};
    std::cout << "Whole vectors equal? " << (std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin())?"yes":"no") << std::endl;
}
```

Now, suppose we only want to compare the first two values (like `[:2]`), Then we would rewrite the last statement to something like this:

```
std::cout << "First 2 values equal? " << (std::equal(a.begin(), a.begin()+2, b.begin())?"yes":"no") << std::endl;
```

Suppose we want to compare the last two values we would do this:

```
std::cout << "Last 2 values equal? " << (std::equal(a.end()-2, a.end(), b.begin())?"yes":"no") << std::endl;
```

See the pattern emerging? `x.begin()+i,x.begin()+j` is roughly equal to `[i:j]`, and `x.end()-i,x.end()-j)` is roughly equal to `[-i,-j]`. Note that you can mix these of course.

So in general when working on containers you will work on a range of iterators and this iterator range can be specified very much alike to python's list splicing. It is more verbose and it is another idiom (spliced lists are lists again but iterators are no containers), but you get the same result.

Some final notes:

- I wrote `x.begin()` to make the code a bit clearer, you can also write `std::begin(x)`, which is more generic and also works on arrays. The same goes for `std::end`
- Take a look to [the algorithms library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) before writing your own for loops over iterators.
- Yes you can write your own for loops (something like `for(auto it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); it++)`, but often it's easier and more consistent to pass a function or lambda to [`std::foreach`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)
- Really remember C++ is not python or vice versa.

Comment: Yes i know that C++ is not Python, but in Python i write application which i can extract/edit strings in binary file, but my application has 12 MB because is write in wxPython so i need rewrite it to C++, but i can find any example to extract strings from binary files. List of strings.

Comment: @Benecore That is a completely different question from how to express python's range operator in C++

Comment: Yes, but i have script for extract strings from binary files and i wanna rewrite it, but i did not know have can rewrite index of array

Comment: @Benecore: as to "index rewriting" my answer still stands. C++ does not really have such things and does not need such things because it has other idioms. If you want to know how to rewrite your given python script with such C++ idioms, ask that question (I suggest as a new one), but do not try to blindly copy a python script to C++ because that will fail horribly. If you want to know about list range operator in C++ terms, well, you got two answers, one why it isn't done and another how you could do it if you really want it.